# How to iterate over 2 arrays and output the shared members without causing an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to work on a program that lets me loop over 2 different lists and outputs the ones on both lists. I'm working with JS (which I'm terrible at) and I keep making infinite loops (the individual lists are huge). I'm so lost.

```
var bmu = ["Ame Nochi Hare", "Ametora", "Amnesia Later", "Ana no Mujina", "Anamorphosis no Meijuu", "Angel Densetsu", "Ani no Senaka", "Ano Ko no Ie", "Ano Ko to Juliet", "Ao no Exorcist", "Aoharu Cynical", "Aoi Uroko to Suna no Machi", "Apart Mate", "Apocalypse no Toride", "Arakawa Under the Bridge", "Are you Alice?", "Aruosumente", "Asa to Micha", "Asagao to Kase-san.", "Asanaga Fuugetsu, Shodouka Desu.", "Ashita wa Docchi Da!", "Assassination Classroom", "Atashin'chi", "Autophagy Regulation", "Ayanashi", "Ayeshah’s Secret", "BADBOYS", "BL of the Dead", "Baby Steps", "Baby, Kokoro no Mama ni!", "Back Stage!!", "Baka de Guzu wa Daikirai", "Baka ga Zenra de Yattekuru", "Ballroom e Youkoso", "Bannou Kanteishi Q no Jikenbo", "Bara to Lion", "Bari Haken", "Bartender", "Beelzebub", "Beelzebub Side Story", "Benkyou Shinasai!", "Berserk", "Law of Ueki", "Skip Beat", "Salaryman Kintarou", "History\'s Strongest Disciple Kenichi", "Naruto"];
var qq = JSON.parse('{\"15\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/m\/mangarchive-r2359\",\"name\":\"Mangarchive\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":null,\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Shindo\",\"id\":\"6308\",\"authors\":[\"SASO Akira\"]}]},\"19\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/w\/wehatemanga-r1453\",\"name\":\"WeHateManga\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":null,\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Happy World!\",\"id\":\"2841\",\"authors\":[\"Takeshita Kenjirou\"]},{\"title\":\"Reo!\",\"id\":\"5224\",\"authors\":[\"SHINGO Asai\"]}]},\"27\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/a\/atlantisdream-r700\",\"name\":\"Atlantisdream\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":\"Inactive Group\",\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Basilis no Musume\",\"id\":\"5990\",\"authors\":[\"SAITOU Chiho\"]},{\"title\":\"Binetsu Shuukan\",\"id\":\"20652\",\"authors\":[\"KUJOU Aoi\"]},{\"title\":\"Missile Happy!\",\"id\":\"17515\",\"authors\":[\"Kiritani Miki\"]},{\"title\":\"Skip Beat!\",\"id\":\"422\",\"authors\":[\"NAKAMURA Yoshiki\"]},{\"title\":\"The Law of Ueki\",\"id\":\"6588\",\"authors\":[\"FUKUCHI Tsubasa\"]}]},\"35\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/c\/chronos-time-guardians-r875\",\"name\":\"Chronos\' Time Guardians\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":\"Inactive\",\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Black Cat\",\"id\":\"1282\",\"authors\":[\"YABUKI Kentaro\"]}]},\"57\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/f\/fuan-r871\",\"name\":\"Fuan\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":\"Inactive Group\",\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Elfen Lied\",\"id\":\"585\",\"authors\":[\"OKAMOTO Lynn\"]},{\"title\":\"Yureka\",\"id\":\"101\",\"authors\":[\"KIM Youn Kyung\",\"Son Hee-joon\"]}]},\"60\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/h\/heavenly-alliance-r433\",\"name\":\"Heavenly-Alliance\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":\"Inactive\",\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Hareluya II Boy\",\"id\":\"185\",\"authors\":[\"UMEZAWA Haruto\"]},{\"title\":\"History\'s Strongest Disciple Kenichi\",\"id\":\"6\",\"authors\":[\"Matsuena Syun\"]},{\"title\":\"Salaryman Kintarou\",\"id\":\"6753\",\"authors\":[\"MOTOMIYA Hiroshi\"]}]},\"90\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/c\/choco-r2221\",\"name\":\"Choco\",\"url\":\"https:\/\/www.mangaupdates.com\/groups.html?id=90\",\"desc\":null,\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Pita-Ten\",\"id\":\"5443\",\"authors\":[\"KOGE Donbo\"]}]},\"91\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/c\/crescent-joy-r1150\",\"name\":\"Crescent Joy\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":\"Inactive Group\",\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Fruits Basket\",\"id\":\"1923\",\"authors\":[\"TAKAYA Natsuki\"]}]},\"92\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/l\/lost-heaven-r1457\",\"name\":\"Lost Heaven\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":\"Inactive\",\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Anata to Scandal\",\"id\":\"5957\",\"authors\":[\"SHIINA Ayumi\"]},{\"title\":\"Handsome na Kanojo\",\"id\":\"5955\",\"authors\":[\"YOSHIZUMI Wataru\"]},{\"title\":\"Karakuri Zoushi Ayatsuri Sakon\",\"id\":\"5149\",\"authors\":[\"SHARAKU Maro\",\"OBATA Takeshi\"]},{\"title\":\"Kaze Hikaru\",\"id\":\"3652\",\"authors\":[\"Watanabe Taeko\"]},{\"title\":\"Luno\",\"id\":\"1453\",\"authors\":[\"TOUME Kei\"]},{\"title\":\"Mushishi\",\"id\":\"4135\",\"authors\":[\"Urushibara Yuki\"]}]}}');

var finArr = [];

for (x in qq) {
    var qt = qq[x];
    console.log(qt, qt.series.length);
    if (qt.series.length !== undefined || qt.series.length !== null) {
       for (i = 0; i < qt.series.length; i++) {
            //console.log(qt.series[i].title, bmu.length);
            for (j = 0; j < bmu.length; j++) {
                //console.log("%c%s", "color: purple", bmu[j].toLowerCase());
               // Infinite loop???
                // if (bmu[j].toLowerCase() !== qt.series[i].title.toLowerCase()) {
                //     //console.log('%c%s' + ' IS NOT IN YOUR LIST', "color: blue", qt.series[i].title.toLowerCase());
                // } else if (bmu[j].toLowerCase() === qt.series[i].title.toLowerCase()) {
                //     //console.log(qt.series[i].title.toLowerCase());
                //     //console.log("%c%s", "color: purple", bmu[j].toLowerCase());
                //     finArr.push(bmu[j].toLowerCase());
                // } else {
                //     console.log('test');
                // }
            } 
        } 
    } else {
        console.log('YOU FAILED EVERYTHING');
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont have to loop on both arrays. Loop on 1 array and check if value exist in other using `array.indexOf`. Also, please share a minimal and verifiable code. Please do not push such a long list, unless required

Comment: There is no infinite loop shown here

Comment: @Rajesh These are highly minimized arrays. Both arrays have about 400+ actual items in them, which looping over both causes Chrome to say it's an infinite loop, so I posted 1/5 of the content so that the escape can be faster for people that that are helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can first get all unique `title`s from `qq`

```
var uniqueTitles = Object.values(qq).reduce( function(a,c){
   c.series.forEach( function(item){
     a.push( item.title.toLowerCase() );
   });
   return a;
} ,[])
```

Now check for common titles

```
bmu = bmu.map( s => s.toLowerCase() ); //converting all items to lowercase before comparison
var output = uniqueTitles.filter( s => bmu.indexOf(s) != -1 );
```

**Demo**

```js
var bmu = ["Ame Nochi Hare", "Ametora", "Amnesia Later", "Ana no Mujina", "Anamorphosis no Meijuu", "Angel Densetsu", "Ani no Senaka", "Ano Ko no Ie", "Ano Ko to Juliet", "Ao no Exorcist", "Aoharu Cynical", "Aoi Uroko to Suna no Machi", "Apart Mate", "Apocalypse no Toride", "Arakawa Under the Bridge", "Are you Alice?", "Aruosumente", "Asa to Micha", "Asagao to Kase-san.", "Asanaga Fuugetsu, Shodouka Desu.", "Ashita wa Docchi Da!", "Assassination Classroom", "Atashin'chi", "Autophagy Regulation", "Ayanashi", "Ayeshah’s Secret", "BADBOYS", "BL of the Dead", "Baby Steps", "Baby, Kokoro no Mama ni!", "Back Stage!!", "Baka de Guzu wa Daikirai", "Baka ga Zenra de Yattekuru", "Ballroom e Youkoso", "Bannou Kanteishi Q no Jikenbo", "Bara to Lion", "Bari Haken", "Bartender", "Beelzebub", "Beelzebub Side Story", "Benkyou Shinasai!", "Berserk", "Law of Ueki", "Skip Beat", "Salaryman Kintarou", "History\'s Strongest Disciple Kenichi", "Naruto"];
var qq = JSON.parse('{\"15\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/m\/mangarchive-r2359\",\"name\":\"Mangarchive\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":null,\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Shindo\",\"id\":\"6308\",\"authors\":[\"SASO Akira\"]}]},\"19\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/w\/wehatemanga-r1453\",\"name\":\"WeHateManga\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":null,\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Happy World!\",\"id\":\"2841\",\"authors\":[\"Takeshita Kenjirou\"]},{\"title\":\"Reo!\",\"id\":\"5224\",\"authors\":[\"SHINGO Asai\"]}]},\"27\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/a\/atlantisdream-r700\",\"name\":\"Atlantisdream\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":\"Inactive Group\",\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Basilis no Musume\",\"id\":\"5990\",\"authors\":[\"SAITOU Chiho\"]},{\"title\":\"Binetsu Shuukan\",\"id\":\"20652\",\"authors\":[\"KUJOU Aoi\"]},{\"title\":\"Missile Happy!\",\"id\":\"17515\",\"authors\":[\"Kiritani Miki\"]},{\"title\":\"Skip Beat!\",\"id\":\"422\",\"authors\":[\"NAKAMURA Yoshiki\"]},{\"title\":\"The Law of Ueki\",\"id\":\"6588\",\"authors\":[\"FUKUCHI Tsubasa\"]}]},\"35\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/c\/chronos-time-guardians-r875\",\"name\":\"Chronos\' Time Guardians\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":\"Inactive\",\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Black Cat\",\"id\":\"1282\",\"authors\":[\"YABUKI Kentaro\"]}]},\"57\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/f\/fuan-r871\",\"name\":\"Fuan\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":\"Inactive Group\",\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Elfen Lied\",\"id\":\"585\",\"authors\":[\"OKAMOTO Lynn\"]},{\"title\":\"Yureka\",\"id\":\"101\",\"authors\":[\"KIM Youn Kyung\",\"Son Hee-joon\"]}]},\"60\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/h\/heavenly-alliance-r433\",\"name\":\"Heavenly-Alliance\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":\"Inactive\",\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Hareluya II Boy\",\"id\":\"185\",\"authors\":[\"UMEZAWA Haruto\"]},{\"title\":\"History\'s Strongest Disciple Kenichi\",\"id\":\"6\",\"authors\":[\"Matsuena Syun\"]},{\"title\":\"Salaryman Kintarou\",\"id\":\"6753\",\"authors\":[\"MOTOMIYA Hiroshi\"]}]},\"90\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/c\/choco-r2221\",\"name\":\"Choco\",\"url\":\"https:\/\/www.mangaupdates.com\/groups.html?id=90\",\"desc\":null,\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Pita-Ten\",\"id\":\"5443\",\"authors\":[\"KOGE Donbo\"]}]},\"91\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/c\/crescent-joy-r1150\",\"name\":\"Crescent Joy\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":\"Inactive Group\",\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Fruits Basket\",\"id\":\"1923\",\"authors\":[\"TAKAYA Natsuki\"]}]},\"92\":{\"bUrl\":\"https:\/\/example.com\/_\/l\/lost-heaven-r1457\",\"name\":\"Lost Heaven\",\"url\":null,\"desc\":\"Inactive\",\"series\":[{\"title\":\"Anata to Scandal\",\"id\":\"5957\",\"authors\":[\"SHIINA Ayumi\"]},{\"title\":\"Handsome na Kanojo\",\"id\":\"5955\",\"authors\":[\"YOSHIZUMI Wataru\"]},{\"title\":\"Karakuri Zoushi Ayatsuri Sakon\",\"id\":\"5149\",\"authors\":[\"SHARAKU Maro\",\"OBATA Takeshi\"]},{\"title\":\"Kaze Hikaru\",\"id\":\"3652\",\"authors\":[\"Watanabe Taeko\"]},{\"title\":\"Luno\",\"id\":\"1453\",\"authors\":[\"TOUME Kei\"]},{\"title\":\"Mushishi\",\"id\":\"4135\",\"authors\":[\"Urushibara Yuki\"]}]}}');


var uniqueTitles = [...Object.values(qq).reduce(function(a, c) {
  c.series.forEach(function(item) {
    a.add(item.title.toLowerCase());
  });
  return a;
}, new Set())]


bmu = bmu.map( s => s.toLowerCase() );
var output = uniqueTitles.filter(s => bmu.indexOf(s) != -1);

console.log(output);
```

**Edit**

Alternatively, as @Nina has suggested you can check for common-ness in the accumulator itself

```
bmu = bmu.map( s => s.toLowerCase() ); 
var commonTitles = Object.values(qq).reduce( function(a,c){
   c.series.forEach( function(item){
     if ( bmu.includes ( item.title.toLowerCase() )
     {
        a.add( item.title );
     }         
   });
   return a;
} ,[])
```

Comment: Interesting use of `Set`. Never seen this before. Learned something new today, thanks.  [Browser Support for Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Yup! Should not be a problem unless IE11 and below needs to be supported. I make it a habit to understand browser compatibility for any new thing I come across in JS so I thought I'll leave it there for anyone else wondering :)

Comment: no need to use an array with the values of the set. this step rith spread and reduce is not necessary, because you could use the set directly for filtering. this requires to insert the values in the same case as the checking case.

Comment: @NinaScholz Didn't thought of this earlier, thanks for pointing out that resultset can be returned in the original case.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using combining [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
// Filter on the simplest array
var commonItems = bmu.filter(function(title){
    // Add the item if at least item in the parsed object contains the same title
    return Object.keys(qq).some(function(key){
        // Check if at least on of the entries in series has the same title
        return qq[key].series.some(function(entry){
            return entry.title.toLowerCase() === title.toLowerCase();
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for the found titles and filter then `bmu` for getting common items.

Both proposals features a collecting of lower case strings for later filtering of the array by using a lower case string to check against.

The proposals use only one (outer) loop for every array.

```js
var bmu = ["Ame Nochi Hare", "Ametora", "Amnesia Later", "Ana no Mujina", "Anamorphosis no Meijuu", "Angel Densetsu", "Ani no Senaka", "Ano Ko no Ie", "Ano Ko to Juliet", "Ao no Exorcist", "Aoharu Cynical", "Aoi Uroko to Suna no Machi", "Apart Mate", "Apocalypse no Toride", "Arakawa Under the Bridge", "Are you Alice?", "Aruosumente", "Asa to Micha", "Asagao to Kase-san.", "Asanaga Fuugetsu, Shodouka Desu.", "Ashita wa Docchi Da!", "Assassination Classroom", "Atashin'chi", "Autophagy Regulation", "Ayanashi", "Ayeshah’s Secret", "BADBOYS", "BL of the Dead", "Baby Steps", "Baby, Kokoro no Mama ni!", "Back Stage!!", "Baka de Guzu wa Daikirai", "Baka ga Zenra de Yattekuru", "Ballroom e Youkoso", "Bannou Kanteishi Q no Jikenbo", "Bara to Lion", "Bari Haken", "Bartender", "Beelzebub", "Beelzebub Side Story", "Benkyou Shinasai!", "Berserk", "Law of Ueki", "Skip Beat", "Salaryman Kintarou", "History\'s Strongest Disciple Kenichi", "Naruto"],
    qq = { "15": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/m/mangarchive-r2359", name: "Mangarchive", url: null, desc: null, series: [{ title: "Shindo", id: "6308", authors: ["SASO Akira"] }] }, "19": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/w/wehatemanga-r1453", name: "WeHateManga", url: null, desc: null, series: [{ title: "Happy World!", id: "2841", authors: ["Takeshita Kenjirou"] }, { title: "Reo!", id: "5224", authors: ["SHINGO Asai"] }] }, "27": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/a/atlantisdream-r700", name: "Atlantisdream", url: null, desc: "Inactive Group", series: [{ title: "Basilis no Musume", id: "5990", authors: ["SAITOU Chiho"] }, { title: "Binetsu Shuukan", id: "20652", authors: ["KUJOU Aoi"] }, { title: "Missile Happy!", id: "17515", authors: ["Kiritani Miki"] }, { title: "Skip Beat!", id: "422", authors: ["NAKAMURA Yoshiki"] }, { title: "The Law of Ueki", id: "6588", authors: ["FUKUCHI Tsubasa"] }] }, "35": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/c/chronos-time-guardians-r875", name: "Chronos' Time Guardians", url: null, desc: "Inactive", series: [{ title: "Black Cat", id: "1282", authors: ["YABUKI Kentaro"] }] }, "57": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/f/fuan-r871", name: "Fuan", url: null, desc: "Inactive Group", series: [{ title: "Elfen Lied", id: "585", authors: ["OKAMOTO Lynn"] }, { title: "Yureka", id: "101", authors: ["KIM Youn Kyung", "Son Hee-joon"] }] }, "60": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/h/heavenly-alliance-r433", name: "Heavenly-Alliance", url: null, desc: "Inactive", series: [{ title: "Hareluya II Boy", id: "185", authors: ["UMEZAWA Haruto"] }, { title: "History's Strongest Disciple Kenichi", id: "6", authors: ["Matsuena Syun"] }, { title: "Salaryman Kintarou", id: "6753", authors: ["MOTOMIYA Hiroshi"] }] }, "90": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/c/choco-r2221", name: "Choco", url: "https://www.mangaupdates.com/groups.html?id=90", desc: null, series: [{ title: "Pita-Ten", id: "5443", authors: ["KOGE Donbo"] }] }, "91": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/c/crescent-joy-r1150", name: "Crescent Joy", url: null, desc: "Inactive Group", series: [{ title: "Fruits Basket", id: "1923", authors: ["TAKAYA Natsuki"] }] }, "92": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/l/lost-heaven-r1457", name: "Lost Heaven", url: null, desc: "Inactive", series: [{ title: "Anata to Scandal", id: "5957", authors: ["SHIINA Ayumi"] }, { title: "Handsome na Kanojo", id: "5955", authors: ["YOSHIZUMI Wataru"] }, { title: "Karakuri Zoushi Ayatsuri Sakon", id: "5149", authors: ["SHARAKU Maro", "OBATA Takeshi"] }, { title: "Kaze Hikaru", id: "3652", authors: ["Watanabe Taeko"] }, { title: "Luno", id: "1453", authors: ["TOUME Kei"] }, { title: "Mushishi", id: "4135", authors: ["Urushibara Yuki"] }] } },
    hash = Object.create(null),
    common = [];

Object.keys(qq).forEach(function (k) {
    qq[k].series.forEach(function (o) {
        hash[o.title.toLowerCase()] = true;
    });
});

common = bmu.filter(function (k) {
    return hash[k.toLowerCase()];
});
    
console.log(common);
```

The same with ES6's [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
var bmu = ["Ame Nochi Hare", "Ametora", "Amnesia Later", "Ana no Mujina", "Anamorphosis no Meijuu", "Angel Densetsu", "Ani no Senaka", "Ano Ko no Ie", "Ano Ko to Juliet", "Ao no Exorcist", "Aoharu Cynical", "Aoi Uroko to Suna no Machi", "Apart Mate", "Apocalypse no Toride", "Arakawa Under the Bridge", "Are you Alice?", "Aruosumente", "Asa to Micha", "Asagao to Kase-san.", "Asanaga Fuugetsu, Shodouka Desu.", "Ashita wa Docchi Da!", "Assassination Classroom", "Atashin'chi", "Autophagy Regulation", "Ayanashi", "Ayeshah’s Secret", "BADBOYS", "BL of the Dead", "Baby Steps", "Baby, Kokoro no Mama ni!", "Back Stage!!", "Baka de Guzu wa Daikirai", "Baka ga Zenra de Yattekuru", "Ballroom e Youkoso", "Bannou Kanteishi Q no Jikenbo", "Bara to Lion", "Bari Haken", "Bartender", "Beelzebub", "Beelzebub Side Story", "Benkyou Shinasai!", "Berserk", "Law of Ueki", "Skip Beat", "Salaryman Kintarou", "History\'s Strongest Disciple Kenichi", "Naruto"],
    qq = { "15": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/m/mangarchive-r2359", name: "Mangarchive", url: null, desc: null, series: [{ title: "Shindo", id: "6308", authors: ["SASO Akira"] }] }, "19": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/w/wehatemanga-r1453", name: "WeHateManga", url: null, desc: null, series: [{ title: "Happy World!", id: "2841", authors: ["Takeshita Kenjirou"] }, { title: "Reo!", id: "5224", authors: ["SHINGO Asai"] }] }, "27": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/a/atlantisdream-r700", name: "Atlantisdream", url: null, desc: "Inactive Group", series: [{ title: "Basilis no Musume", id: "5990", authors: ["SAITOU Chiho"] }, { title: "Binetsu Shuukan", id: "20652", authors: ["KUJOU Aoi"] }, { title: "Missile Happy!", id: "17515", authors: ["Kiritani Miki"] }, { title: "Skip Beat!", id: "422", authors: ["NAKAMURA Yoshiki"] }, { title: "The Law of Ueki", id: "6588", authors: ["FUKUCHI Tsubasa"] }] }, "35": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/c/chronos-time-guardians-r875", name: "Chronos' Time Guardians", url: null, desc: "Inactive", series: [{ title: "Black Cat", id: "1282", authors: ["YABUKI Kentaro"] }] }, "57": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/f/fuan-r871", name: "Fuan", url: null, desc: "Inactive Group", series: [{ title: "Elfen Lied", id: "585", authors: ["OKAMOTO Lynn"] }, { title: "Yureka", id: "101", authors: ["KIM Youn Kyung", "Son Hee-joon"] }] }, "60": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/h/heavenly-alliance-r433", name: "Heavenly-Alliance", url: null, desc: "Inactive", series: [{ title: "Hareluya II Boy", id: "185", authors: ["UMEZAWA Haruto"] }, { title: "History's Strongest Disciple Kenichi", id: "6", authors: ["Matsuena Syun"] }, { title: "Salaryman Kintarou", id: "6753", authors: ["MOTOMIYA Hiroshi"] }] }, "90": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/c/choco-r2221", name: "Choco", url: "https://www.mangaupdates.com/groups.html?id=90", desc: null, series: [{ title: "Pita-Ten", id: "5443", authors: ["KOGE Donbo"] }] }, "91": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/c/crescent-joy-r1150", name: "Crescent Joy", url: null, desc: "Inactive Group", series: [{ title: "Fruits Basket", id: "1923", authors: ["TAKAYA Natsuki"] }] }, "92": { bUrl: "https://example.com/_/l/lost-heaven-r1457", name: "Lost Heaven", url: null, desc: "Inactive", series: [{ title: "Anata to Scandal", id: "5957", authors: ["SHIINA Ayumi"] }, { title: "Handsome na Kanojo", id: "5955", authors: ["YOSHIZUMI Wataru"] }, { title: "Karakuri Zoushi Ayatsuri Sakon", id: "5149", authors: ["SHARAKU Maro", "OBATA Takeshi"] }, { title: "Kaze Hikaru", id: "3652", authors: ["Watanabe Taeko"] }, { title: "Luno", id: "1453", authors: ["TOUME Kei"] }, { title: "Mushishi", id: "4135", authors: ["Urushibara Yuki"] }] } },
    hash = new Set,
    common = [];

Object
    .values(qq)
    .forEach(({ series }) => series.forEach(({ title }) => hash.add(title.toLowerCase())));

common = bmu.filter(k => hash.has(k.toLowerCase()));
    
console.log(common);
```

Answer (score 0):

To me the code seem much more complicated that it needs to be, try something like this.

```
for(x in qq){
 for(y in bmu){
   if(qq[x].name.toLowerCase() == bmu[y].toLowerCase())
   {
    console.log("Found: "+bmu[y]);
   }
  else if(qq[x].series.length > 0)
  {
    for(z in qq[x].series)
    {
      if(qq[x].series[z].title.toLowerCase() == bmu[y].toLowerCase())
      {
        console.log("Found: "+bmu[y]);
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```